# How to export data from excel specific cells into mathematica?

Tags: export, excel

How to export data from excel specific cells into *Mathematica*? Given that the spreadsheet tab is named XYZ and that I have several cells at various locations in the same column in Excel that I want to export?

Comment: This seems more of an Excel question than a _Mathematica_ question.

Comment: I think that this question is absolute valid. This [link](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/XLSX.html) from Wolfram can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is verbatim from the docs on [`XLSX`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/XLSX.html):

Example excel file with two sheets:

```
 Export["sheets.xlsx", {{"MySheet1" -> {Range[10]}, 
   "MySheet2" -> {{"This is a string."}}}}, {{"Sheets"}}]
```

To import the cell at row 1, column 4 of `MySheet1`:

```
 Import["sheets.xlsx", {"Sheets", "MySheet1", 1, 4}]
 (*  4 *)
```

Import the second sheet:

```
 Import["sheets.xlsx", {"Sheets", 2}]
 (* {{"This is a string."}} *)
```

Comment: @sebastian, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.