# Import selective elements from mixed (text and numbers) data file

Tags: import, data

How can I import only the 2nd and 5th elements (numbers, located in the 2nd and 5th columns) from all n raws of a data file (.xlxx) that contains both numbers and text. Imported data be inserted into a constant array. Thanks

Comment: related/possible duplicate  q/a [...from Excel specific cells into Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13650/125)

Answer (score 3):

Even though I don't see it in the documentation, you can use `All` when specifying what elements you want to import.

So for an example Excel spreadsheet:

[image]

We can import the 2nd and 5th elements from every row on the first sheet as such:

```
Import["pathtoxlsx.xlsx", {"Data", 1, All, {2, 5}}]
```

> {{0.612328, 0.325049}, {0.909502, 0.206016}, {0.531286, 
>     0.267417}, {0.441283, 0.714645}, {0.369051, 0.581077}, {0.421404, 
>     0.598902}, {0.859646, 0.817586}, {0.477507, 0.820588}, {0.915968, 
>     0.559369}, {0.962673, 0.944758}, {0.803255, 0.166438}, {0.483266, 
>     0.661242}, {0.499209, 0.159238}, {0.554271, 0.593598}, {0.0609692, 
>     0.528343}, {0.046578, 0.922516}, {0.715221, 0.00963152}, {0.134301, 
>     0.448886}, {0.0765122, 0.701141}, {0.130223, 0.132252}, {0.474112, 
>     0.0138053}, {0.342081, 0.125728}, {0.274643, 0.0554139}}

Comment: Truly brilliant. All the more so since the `Documentation` for `Import` is so short.

Comment: nice. does this perform any different vs `Import[...][[1,All,{2,3}]]`

Comment: Just checked that, it is in fact faster to import the whole works and take what you need afterward.

Comment: Thanks Kale and George, I am really a novice. Just starting my first steps, so sorry for the really simple questions. Did like Kale recommended and got as out :out[2]= import["desktop/ipxi/4136928.xlsx", {"data", 1, All, {2, 4}}]  How can I actually se the results like in Kale's example?

Comment: Assaf -> Open it in excel

Comment: Question - what is the function of the number 1 after the "Data" keyword? what is it telling mathematica?

Comment: @TomMozdzen  `1` = First worksheet within the workbook. `All` = All rows. `{2,5}` = columns 2 and 5.